Identify this set: bag with black, grey and black parts & 6-pointed star
Hi I got a massive bag of Lego today. In it I found those bags 4, 5 and 6. Can anyone identify what set is coming from?
The pic below is from pack 6

Does this answer your question? How can I identify a set based on one or more original sealed bags?

Based on Trans-Dark-Blue Projectile Arrow, Bar 8L with Round End (Spring Shooter Dart)
 and a bit of searching, this is part of set 71738 "Zane's Titan Mech Battle".

Note this is one of only two sets that carry part 41125 "Technic Circular Saw Blade with Pin Hole and Six Teeth (Large Shuriken Throwing Star)" in flat silver.
